# Python displaying output same as source code

Tags: python, cgi

I am running hello.py hosted on a live server in a directory. 
Following is the code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

When I run this via putty by using the following command from my directory:-

python hello.py

It executes well in the shell. But I run this from a browser , for ex.
www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/hello.py

The whole of the source code comes as output . The following is the output:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

So you can see that in the browser the output and source code are same .
I am new to python programming so please excuse for anything naive. 
Please help me know how it can display the correct output by parsing html.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to configure your webserver to treat python scripts as CGI. But it's 2014; you should not be writing CGI scripts at all. Choose a WSGI framework like Django or Flask and use that. You'll be much happier.

Comment: Actaully the plain python is my main requirement for now and its very urgent . Can you guide me how to write cgi scripts ? Or refer to any resource ? Thanks

Comment: What webserver are you using? Consult its manual about how to set different file extensions to be treated as CGI.

Comment: @Wooble : The problem is that my cgi-bin is not in a directory accessible on web its somewhere else. Its in /usr/lib/cgi-bin
but web access is /var/www/sites/mydomain/ . But all the tutorials on the web refer to cgi-bin folder being in web accessible directory. Any idea on this ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

By just printing the HTML code it won't work. You need to write a server. Check the CGI module for starters. But since CGI is old also look into WSGI Frameworks like Django and App Engine.